# How to Stop Datagridview flickering on every datasource update in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, refresh, datasource

i have a datgridview whose datasource is updated every second. The datagridview `datagridview_1` flickers vigorously on every update. The form receives data and then populates it into a data table "`temp_dt`" and then the data table is copied into the DataSource.

The order of the procedure is.

```
 call_populatedata(data_to_be_populated);
 datagridview_1.DataSource=temp_dt;
 datagridview_1.Refresh();
```

But this does not helps.

Comment: How often you update the `DataSource` ?

Comment: every second the data source is updated

Comment: Just update the data, don't set the new data source. You can use `BindingList<T>` where `T` is your entity class which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Can you explain in brief how  to do this?

Comment: Search for datagridview databinding, you'll find lots of tutorials. Follow this http://tech.pro/tutorial/776/csharp-tutorial-binding-a-datagridview-to-a-collection any problem, feel free to come back.